# need help getting batch file to read input but it works fine on the first part strangely

Tags: batch-file

so heres my code the first part executes perfectly but the second doesnt it just displays each variable as blank. im not sure why as its formatted the same also would it be possible to put the :readprofiles part in a working for variable?:

purpose of the program: to list out a directory as profiles along with numbered choices to select. basically a menu.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set Counter=1
for /f "DELIMS=" %%i in (test.txt) do (
    set "Line_!Counter!=%%i"
    set /a Counter+=1
)
set /a NumLines=Counter - 1

:: this part is a test
echo %Line_1%
echo %Line_2%
echo %Line_3%
echo %Line_4%
echo %Line_5%
echo %Line_6%
:: end test

set Counter=1

:readprofiles
if %Counter%==%NumLines% goto pause
echo %Counter%. %Line_!Counter!%
set /a Counter+=1
goto readprofiles

:pause
pause
```

Comment: `echo %Counter%. !Line_%Counter%!`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set Counter=0
for /f "DELIMS=" %%i in (test.txt) do (
    set /a Counter+=1
    set "Line_!Counter!=%%i"
)
For /L %%C in (1,1,%Counter%) Do echo %%C. !Line_%%C!
Pause
```